# Найти индекс во вложенном списке и изменить значение по индексу

Tags: python, список, бот, telegram

Суть проблемы такова, ломаю голову третий день, хотя на первый взгляд все просто.
Нужно написать бота, который создает список по ЮЗЕР ИД и присваивает к каждому ИД цифру 1.
Как только человек с юзер ид из списка пишет сообщение, нужно в списке с его ид заменить 1 на 2 и так далее. Формат списка такой [[56310020, 1], [325425453,1], ........ [245345534534,1]] Первое это юзер ИД второе количество сообщений.
Но проблема в  том, что когда делаю поиск по ИД, выдает ошибку что такого ИД в списке нет ValueError: 56310020 is not in list, при это программа начинаеться именно с добавления ИД.
Помогите разобраться.

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('.....')
users = []
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def add(message):
    if message.from_user.id not in users:
        users.append([message.from_user.id, 1]) #заношу в список юзер ИД и количество сообщений

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text']) #когда пишет текст
def shet(message):
    id = message.from_user.id
    if id in users:           # проверка на наличие ИД в списке
        print(users.index(id)) # найти индекс нужного ИД

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Id у тебя не с списке users, а во вложенных списках. Там и нужно искать. Но лучше использовать словарь.

Answer (score 0):

Как было сказано [в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1445434/%d0%9d%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%83/1445460#comment2580653_1445434), надо искать индекс во вложенных списках, вот так:

```
id = message.from_user.id
for i, sub in enumerate(users):
    if id == sub[0]:
        print(i) # индекс юзера, id которого мы искали
```

Если что-то непонятно по поводу `enumerate`, все есть [в документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: Надеюсь, я вам помог =)